# package javax.servlet does not exist on Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, netbeans, japplet

I am writing JApplet in Netbeans. My applet is working, so I decide to add servlet because I want to have log in/out. When I added servlet to my project as follows:

```
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
```

I had the following errors:

```
error: package javax.servlet does not exist 
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
error: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
```

Apache Tomcat is working.

Answer (score 1):

Add [servlet jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavaxservlet30jar.htm) to the classpath in your IDE. Your webcontainer will provide it at runtime. You don't have to bundle it in your WAR

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lmIi8lm8ti8)

Under Libraries Folder in the Project Window, Right-click and "Add Library...", then choose Java EE web 8 API